# Setup Excel 2007 To Open New Sheets In New Window

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

If my users have Excel 2007 open and double click on another Excel document in explorer (or goto file open and open a new one), this document is opened within the same window.

Can I configure every new document to open in its own separate window?  I'm sure I'm probably missing an obvious configuration setting here.

Is there a way to configure this globally via GPO or something?

Comment: No. It is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly http://www.eceblogger.com/2008/08/where-did-the-multiple-windows-go-in-excel-2007/ ?

(I think that will open two copies of Excel with two windows, with a document in each. Not one copy of Excel with two documents and two windows. I don't think the latter is possible anymore).

Comment: Yes, the proper way to do this is to open Excel twice and File>>Open from there. I find it annoying too I must admit, but there you go.